# Jquery, how to put an event on prefixed class named inputs?

Tags: jquery

I have to do an auto validate stuff, so I must put `.blur()` and `.focus()` event handlers on input fields which have the 'checkMe' prefix in their `class` attribute, so they will look alike 'class="checkMe-required"', 'class="checkMe-mustBeInt"', 'class="checkMe-mustBeDate"' and so on. How to do this? This `$('.checkMe-*').focus(function() {` aint work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "[starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

```
$("[class^='checkMe']")
```

However, performance-wise, it would probably be better to have a `checkMe` class and add the other part as a second class:

```
<input class="checkMe required" type="text>
```

Then you can use the normal class selector:

```
$(".checkMe")
```